# Azure: how to authenticate service api call

Tags: node.js, azure

Am trying to call `notificationHub` service api using `node.js` SDK. I generated key "token" following this page of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal)

Then in my `node.js` app i had the following code:

```
  const client = new notificationHubsClient(AZURE_KEY, AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
  console.log('the client', client);
```

However i got this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: credentials argument needs to implement signRequest method
```

So far am using the token i generated previously as credentials not sure if that correct, from the docs:

```
var client = new notificationHubsClient(credentials, 'your-subscription-id');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I suppose that you are using [azure-sdk-for-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node). And according to [the documentation here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/Documentation/Authentication.md), we should generate the credentials like this:

```
const Azure = require('azure');
const MsRest = require('ms-rest-azure');

MsRest.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(
  'clientId or appId',
  'secret or password',
  'domain or tenant',
  (err, credentials) => {
    if (err) throw err

    var client = new notificationHubsClient(credentials, 'your-subscription-id');
  }
);
```

Comment: According to the documentation this the third method to do it which i didn't want to use to not provide my password in the code, however the first method is using the protal which i followed to get a token. Am not sure what is credentials i thought it's only the token.

Comment: You can store the secret in environment variables rather than in the source code for your project. See the sample code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/examples/ARM/compute/vm-sample.js#L23

Comment: Yeah, true `.env` is really good, however my question is how ill do it using the first method using the protal, but if i got no good answer will use the third method and accept your answer, thank you.